# Out of these two monitors which one to buy?

Tags: monitors

I found these two monitors at Costco
LG 27MN60T - 27 inches with 5 ms response time. Price $140. [Link](https://go.redirectingat.com/?id=92X1584492&xcust=tomshardware_us_8315880704648721000&xs=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.costco.com%2Flg-27%2522-class-fhd-ips-freesync-monitor.product.100676476.html&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.tomshardware.com%2Fthreads%2Fwhich-monitor-i-should-buy-between-these-two.3789154%2F). [Spec sheet](https://go.redirectingat.com/?id=92X1584492&xcust=tomshardware_us_1210543290356655000&xs=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmobilecontent.costco.com%2Flive%2Fresource%2Fimg%2Fstatic-us-pdf%2F8276020-Spec_Sheet.pdf&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.tomshardware.com%2Fthreads%2Fwhich-monitor-i-should-buy-between-these-two.3789154%2F)
Samsung S32b300nwn - 32 inches with 8 ms response time. Price $160. [Link](https://www.costco.com/samsung-32%22-class-s30b-series-fhd-amd-freesync-monitor.product.4000045047.html). Spec sheet

LG is based on IPS while Samsung is based on VA. Followed this [link](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/learn/ips-vs-va-vs-tn).
Both has same resolution and same refresh rate. Both has AMD Freesync technology.

**Which computer it is connected?** This [one](https://go.redirectingat.com/?id=92X1584492&xcust=tomshardware_us_2032946474211107000&xs=1&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.costco.com%2Fhp-victus-gaming-desktop-amd-ryzen-7-5700g-radeon-rx-6600xt.product.4000056482.html&sref=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.tomshardware.com%2Fthreads%2Fwhich-monitor-i-should-buy-between-these-two.3789154%2F)
It's for my elementary son who is not too much in gaming now. Mostly the computer will be used for youtube.,com video, learning and light gaming.
Size really doesn't matter as the kiddos' room is around 12 X 14.

I am really confused in terms of which monitor to choose?

Comment: IPS is generally better

Comment: The links to the 2nd one is missing

Comment: IPS maintains good picture quality from most viewing angles (above/below, far to the side) so it will make a good "TV" for a bedroom. A VA panel has extremely poor image quality viewed from below, almost unwatchable, so it has to have a good stand to tilt/turn it to face you perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer between the two, but an alternative option.

For a big size monitor, 27 inch and certainly 32 inch, 1920 x 1080 resolution (aka 1080p, or FHD) is pretty low.

Maybe go with this **Acer KA272U** ([$159.42 now on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JQSBNYH))

- 27 Inch
- Resolution: 2560 x 1440 (1440p, QHD)
- IPS Panel

Comment: 27in 1080p is not too bad when it comes to pixel density, except if you are really sitting close to the monitor (which I only do with my laptop)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have looked at each on display and working in the store yourself... simply choose which one looks nice and which **size** you are more happy with.

The response time and IPS is irrelevant in your case.

Both are 1920 x 1080 resolution, which is low by today's standards, and the smaller 27" monitor would likely have a *nicer* display than the larger 32" one.  But again choose which ever seems to just look like a better monitor, given both are 1920x1080.

A 27" monitor at 2560 x 1440 resolution is, or had been, the sweet spot in my opinion.  The typical monitor today is 32" at 4k (4096 x 2160) resolution but do know that a 4k monitor requires a decent graphics card to drive it to play *good* games, not so much basic [youtube] video, so if gaming is an eventual want know that if you run a 4k monitor you'll likely be spending $500 on a decent graphics card to drive that 4k resolution.

The IPS vs VA (whatever manufacturing technology), 8ms vs 5ms response time, refresh rate... all mostly not an issue when the biggest factor really is, is when your kid will eventually scratch the display.

make sure the monitor connection (dvi, dp, hdmi) is compatible with your existing pc or graphics card.